# How to calculate duration of array combination function in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a function below which generates a set of combinations for an array, at various lengths, defined by a range. I'd like to be able to get data about the combination process which would include the time required to process the combinations. Given the following:

```
source = ("a".."z").to_a
range = 1..7
```

The command to generate the combinations is this:

```
  combinations = (range).flat_map do |size|
    source.combination(size).to_a
  end
```

This command takes about 5 seconds to run on my machine, and generates 971,711 combinations. However, when I try to execute this in the context of a function, below:

```
def combinations(source, range)
  time_start = Time.now

  combinations = (range).flat_map do |size|
    source.combination(size).to_a
  end

  time_elapsed = (Time.now - time_start).round(1)
  puts "Generated #{combinations.count} in #{time_elapsed} seconds."
  return combinations
end

source = ("a".."z").to_a
range = 1..7

combinations(source, range)
```

The function almost immediately outputs:

```
Generated 971711 in 0.1 seconds.
```

... and then 5 seconds later returns the combinations. What's going on here? And how can I calculate the duration of the time required to process the combinations?

Comment: try `combinations.to_a` in the clocked region. Maybe it's lazy due to infinite ranges?

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code on ruby 2.0.0p247 on an Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit machine, I get the output:

```
Generated 971711 in 0.6 seconds.
```

and the program exits immediately after that.

Since there is only one `puts` line in the program what do you mean by "and then 5 seconds later returns the combinations"?  Is there more code that you are not showing us?  What ruby interpreter are you running?  What operating system?  Could you provide the full code if you have not yet?

If you want to look into this more, I recommend trying [rblineprof](https://github.com/tmm1/rblineprof) or [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Hi David. I'm running ruby 1.9.3p429 on Mac OS X 10.8.4. When I say it returns 5 seconds later I meant that all the combinations are output in irb. Thanks for the links, I'll check those out.

Comment: OK, so you are running this in IRB.  It sounds like it takes 5 seconds or so to format the string that represents the 971k combinations before it gets printed on the screen.  That is not surprising.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the issue here is that the ruby is taking the ~ 5 seconds to be able to load and display the information in IRB, but the "Generated X in Y seconds." information is actually correct and working. It was just less than I was expecting because I was confused about the difference between the time required to calculate the combinations vs the time required to load and start displaying the output of the combinations.